# C# write and read appsettings and log files best practice (UAC Program Files x86)

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, settings

I have the following scenario:

**1.** A running Windows Service that collects some data (files) that should be stored in a central place. To know which files have to be stored I like to have a configuration.xml file or something like that. And also writing some logs.

**2.** With a small windows form application I like to have the ability to change the settings in that configuration.xml file.

**First Problem:** Many people here in this forum suggest to use the AppData Folder to store application settings. But in my eyes I can´t do this because its possible that another user is logged in to the computer. (different user folders) And also the collected files should be stored every time in the same folder and not different users folders.

**Second Problem:** If I try to use the Program Files (x86) folder I get a permission denied error even if the user is member of the local administrator group.

I have seen a lot of applications that are doing similar things and that can write to the Program Files (x86) folder (example: log files) without prompting the user to elevate the rights (manifest)

Any ideas how does this work?

ApplicationName: pop_consoleApp2.exe
Manifest-fileName: pop_consoleApp2.exe.manifest

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="pop_consoleApp2"
     type="win32"/>
  <description>Description of your application</description>
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="highestAvailable"
          uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the common application data folder (Normally named 'Program Data', a hidden folder on your systems drive root). It's an none roaming user independent application data folder. It's location is given in this variable:

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
```

There you could create a subfolder for your application. Additionally you could/should set permissions on that folder at setup time of your service (E.G. Service Account read/write, all users read access).

Comment: ok thanks this is a good idea for the application settings and could work for me. But what is with the collected data that I like to store in a central place...? I think not that this is a correct place for storing a big amount of data? But you put me a step forward, thanks again.

Comment: This folder is perfectly fine for a large amount of data as long as you don't expect your users to browse this data via a file explorer. Have a look at this blog entry: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `app.manifest` file to your project to give `elevated permission` to user -

By default if you simply add manifest file in your project, you will see following line in your file -

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Replace `level` attribute to `highestAvailable` -

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

Refer to link here from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I already posted I don´t like to get the UAC prompt to confirm this. I already know this way with the app.manifest... But I this is only working with the prompt...?

Comment: No it won't. Check the link i added from `msdn`. I have been using this for my project without any prompt.

Comment: mh... I tried it again with no success... I get the prompt at the start from my application...? I posted above my manifest file, any idea?